# encrypt href link in url using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
file:///C:/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/studentInfo.html
```

I want to encrypt the `studentInfo.html` into characters like for example

`file:///C:/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/A%1fs%fdd.html`

using javascript? How can I do this?

Comment: And what is this unique encryption? It is unclear what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

You could encode it in [Base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) with with the `atob()` (decode) and `btoa()` (encode) javascript fonctions.

```
var path = "file:///C:/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/"
var file = "studentInfo.html"
console.log(path + btoa(file))
// Output: file:///C:/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/c3R1ZGVudEluZm8uaHRtbA==
```